# Google maps API V3 - Two location with markers on same map

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display two different location on map at same time, one is current location and other one is different location. I use javascript V3 version. This is my code for display one location.

```
         var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);


             window.localStorage.setItem("event_location",pos);

             if (!google) {
                    loadScript();
                }
             var pos1 = window.localStorage.getItem("current_location");
                alert('position '+pos1);

                var myOptions = {
                    center : pos,
                    zoom : 8,
                    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };


                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

                var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<h4 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+add+'</h4> ' +
                '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                '<p>Meeting with'+'<b> '+ personName + '</b>, <br/>on ' +
                '<b>'+startDate+'</b> at ' + 
                '<b>'+startTime+'</b>' + 
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';


            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                title:"Event Location!"
            });



            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
```

pos1 is my second location which is calculated by phonegap current location method. Please help me out.

Comment: Please show how the location is stored ? I mean what will be the value of `pos1` ? a string ?

Comment: if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function success(position){
     
     var position = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
      position.coords.longitude);
     window.localStorage.setItem("current_location",position);
    });
  } else {
    alert('geolocation not supported');
  }                                                        pos1 is position.

Answer (score 0):

If `pos1` is `google.maps.LatLng` instance

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    map: map,
    title:"Event Location!"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos1,
    map: map,
    title:"New Location!"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker1);
});

marker.setMap(map);
marker1.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Yes . As you said " Two location with markers on same map " :)

Comment: But its not working, it gave me error "Console(15022): Uncaught Error: Invalid value for property <position>: (28.6048506, 77.36979930000007) at http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/8/5/main.js:1
"

Comment: Actually the demo which you gave me, its only for static value, but in my case i generate the value through code.

Comment: Yes that is just a demo. Thought you would be able to modify it. See this example. Click add button, enter comma separated lan and lng.
http://jsfiddle.net/diode/6A6xL/4/

Comment: Again its not working, it gave me error on position property of marker1.

Comment: Ok.. got the issue. You cannot store and retrieve marker latlng in localstoreage directly. Either you have to store lat and lng separately or extract the values as shown in this http://jsfiddle.net/diode/6A6xL/5/

Comment: But if I put the alert the I got right value of my current location, means i able to fetch it.

Comment: Ok, your point is right, then how i show my current location.

Comment: Yes values are correct , but not in the format we need. `var pos1 = window.localStorage.getItem("current_location");` will return a string like this `(28.6048506, 77.36979930000007)` from which we have to extract `28.6048506` and `77.36979930000007` and then make the instance of `google.maps.LatLng`. Only then it will work.

Comment: zoom down and see whether it is anywhere on the map.

Comment: Yes, but when I put this line " var pos1Array = pos1String.match(/\d+/g);", then it gave me not my current location. it show somewhere else.

Comment: please put your code here and send the link. http://jsfiddle.net/ no other way to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

write the code for displaying the second marker  i.e. if u have the lat long for pos1  create a marker and display it on the same map. it will hardly take milliseconds to display the secod marker if the client browser has got reasonable processing capacity